# How to make a auto presser on android?

Tags: android

I want to make a auto presser on android.
how can I make a app that presses by itself? is there a function for click?
can someone give me the idea of how I can do that please?

Comment: This makes no sense, why not just call the code that gets executed when the click happens?

Comment: I want to go to other apps on the device detect something and then make the device press by itself

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `performClick()` method. An example can be like this :-

```
mButton.performClick();
```

Comment: That's not what I want... you made a button on the application and let him do a click... I want to make a application that run on the background of the device and make touches on the screen

Comment: I don't think there is a solution for this problem